# I'm unable to trigger validations in Parsley when a single field emits a success event without infinite recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, recursion, parsley.js

I have a number of different sections in a form, and the inputs from each section must equal the very first input (in it's own section) for the form to be validated.

The validations are working correctly, the only problem is that the UI displays errors in the rest of the section in the case where a user attempts to validate when a section has incorrect figures in it.  In that case, there are errors displayed on each input in the section.  This is great.  However, when a user changes the number in one of the fields, and the total is now correct, parsley only clears the error in that particular field.

Here is the code that works fine, except for not clearing the errors:

```
window.ParsleyValidator
    .addValidator('sumTotal', function (value, group) {
        // get total enrollment number
        var totalInput = $('#enrollment-group').find('[data-parsley-sum-total="all"]')
        var totalEnrollment = parseInt(totalInput.val())
        // sum up input values for the section
        var sectionSum = 0;
        $('#enrollment-group').find('[data-parsley-sum-total="' + group + '"]').each(function(){
            if ($(this).val()) sectionSum += parseInt($(this).val()); 
        })
        // if no inputs, don't consider the section
        if (sectionSum === 0)  return true
        return totalEnrollment === sectionSum;
    }, 32)
    .addMessage('en', 'sumTotal', 'The total sum for all %s fields must equal the total enrollment above: ' + $('#enrollment-group').find('[data-parsley-sum-total="all"]').val());
// exclude the 'total enrollment' input from the sum validation
$('form').parsley({ excluded: '[data-parsley-sum-total="all"]' });
```

And here's one example of code that I tried to clear the errors with, but ended up with infinite recursion:

```
$('form').parsley().subscribe('parsley:field:success', function(input){

    $.each($('[data-parsley-sum-total]'), function(i, value){
        if ($(value).hasClass('parsley-error')){
            $(value).parsley().validate()
        }
    })
});
```

So, *how do I clear all the errors on the inputs in a section once the section is valid?*

This is in a django admin template, so I have to add my custom validator after parsley.js is loaded.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so after some more fiddling around I figured it out, here it is for anyone who is having a similar problem:

```
window.ParsleyValidator
    .addValidator('sumTotal', function (value, group) {
        // get total enrollment number
        var totalInput = $('#enrollment-group').find('[data-parsley-sum-total="all"]')
        var totalEnrollment = parseInt(totalInput.val())
        // sum up input values for the section
        var sectionSum = 0;
        $('#enrollment-group').find('[data-parsley-sum-total="' + group + '"]').each(function(){
            if ($(this).val()) sectionSum += parseInt($(this).val()); 
        })
        // if no inputs, don't consider the section
        if (sectionSum === 0)  return true
        return totalEnrollment === sectionSum;
    }, 32)
    .addMessage('en', 'sumTotal', 'The total sum for all %s fields must equal the total enrollment above: ' + $('#enrollment-group').find('[data-parsley-sum-total="all"]').val());
// exclude the 'total enrollment' input from the sum validation
$('form').parsley({ excluded: '[data-parsley-sum-total="all"]' });
// clear other errors in section if one field emits success event
$('form').parsley().subscribe('parsley:field:success', function(input){
    $.each($('[data-parsley-sum-total]'), function(i, value){
        if ($(value).attr('data-parsley-sum-total') == input.options.sumTotal){
            window.ParsleyUI.removeError($(value).parsley(), 'sumTotal')
            $(value).removeClass('parsley-error')
            $(value).addClass('parsley-success')
        }
    })
})
```